# How to detect obstacle position using point cloud data?

Tags: python, turtlebot, ros-kinetic, ubuntu, gazebo-ros-openni-kinect

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Everyone,

I am working on turtlebot and kinect sensor. I want to detect obstacle presence and its position using kinect sensor. How could I do this and I am not using maps. Just want to know whether obstacle is there or not. And if I am going to use point cloud libraries, how can i get obstacle position(X,Y) .

(I am using Ros kinetic version,Ubuntu 16.04 and python as coding language.)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/320560/how-to--detect-obstacle-position-using-point-cloud-data?/) by [GLV](https://answers.ros.org/users/37187/glv/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2019-04-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is pretty broad and generic. I'd suggest that you look through some of the PCL tutorials: http://wiki.ros.org/pcl/Tutorials

You can also just read the position data out of the point cloud data structure manually.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2019-04-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [GLV](https://answers.ros.org/users/37187/glv/) on 2019-04-09**:
Thanks for your answer #Mr.tfoote. This tutorials in C++ can i get in python anywhere?
Could you pls give me some suggestions to how to start?

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2019-04-12**:
There's a few python methods to help with this here: https://github.com/ros/common_msgs/blob/jade-devel/sensor_msgs/src/sensor_msgs/point_cloud2.py

**Comment by [GLV](https://answers.ros.org/users/37187/glv/) on 2019-04-15**:
Thank you so much #Mr.tfoote

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2019-04-15**:
Please accept the answer using the check mark at the left so others know that this is answered and it can be filter appropriately.

**Comment by [GLV](https://answers.ros.org/users/37187/glv/) on 2019-04-16**:
In order to get a position I have to launch this code  https://github.com/ros/common_msgs/bl.. or I need to clone all package???